# Design issue regarding serializing , deserializing

Tags: c++, design-patterns, polymorphism

I have many classes , say,

```
class A
{
/*member variables*/
};

class B .. Class Z
```

I am copying objects of these classes into a buffer (char*). Now I have a reader object that continuously polls this buffer and deserializes the bytes into objects and prints them. My question is how should the deserialzer class be designed.

The approach I have is to embed the type of the object as a header and then send it through the buffer.  Upon reading the buffer, I know the type and then I can deserialize the appropriate object. The problem with the deserializing part is now it should be aware of all the message types and call the appropriate function based on the type. I am planning to have this deserialization as a separate entity that is not aware of the message types or the code to deserialze it should not be a part of it.

I am looking for solutions like interfaces, polymorphism etc. to tackle this problem. Is there a design pattern for this kind of a problem ?

Comment: perhaps this: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html will be useful to you (boost::serialization) ;)

Comment: Also look into whether you need to do this yourself. Check https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/ , https://thrift.apache.org/ or https://avro.apache.org/.

Answer (score 0):

First question, are the reader and writer on the same translation unit?

If yes, then you can have polymorphic classes. A base class `Message` and derived classes from it. The reader reads the buffer as `Message*` and then calls the overridden virtual functions to get required information about the derived class.

If no, then you can have type-to-int codes inserted into the message.